# PUT and GET single element not working at DJANGO using rest-api. (BUT POST & GET WORKS!)

Tags: python, django, get, django-rest-framework, put

I'm trying to work with django & rest api. The get & post functions are working for me, (for example at /users/).
But when i'm trying to access a specific user, I receive this error:

```
TypeError at /users/1 put()
 missing 1 required positional argument: 'pk'
```

I think it has something to do with the urls.

Code of UserList, getElement and put doesn't work

```
class UserList(APIView):
    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    ''' Returns list of all users in json format '''
    def get(self, request):
        #print("In get")
        #print("pk: "+pk)
        users = User.objects.all()
        serializedUsers = UserSerializer(users, many=True)
        return Response(serializedUsers.data)

    def getElement(self, request, pk):
        print("Inside put. pk: " + str(pk))
        user = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = UserSerializer(user, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            #serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


    ''' Enables to add new user to DB '''
    def post(self, request):
        print("In post USER")
        response = Response({"message": "Added user", "data": request.data})
        deserializedUser = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if deserializedUser.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            deserializedUser.save()
            return response
        else:
            print("Error occured")
            return Response(deserializedUser.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    ''' Enables to update existing user in the DB '''
    def put(self, request, pk, format=None):
        print("Inside put. pk: " + str(pk))
        user = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = UserSerializer(user, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

This is a part in the urls file:

```
    urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^users/', views.UserList.as_view()),
    url(r'^users/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', views.UserList.as_view()),
    url(r'^routes/', views.RouteList.as_view()),
    url(r'^runs/', views.RunList.as_view()),
]

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

I've seen the r'^users/(?P[0-9]+)$' somewhere so I guess it's good, But i'm not sure which function I need call.

Thank you all in advance :)

Comment: show your view code as text, please

Comment: I added the code as text after addition, thank you